# Unde "Laelaps"?

Tags: greek, etymology, names, mythology

Laelaps was a mythical hunting dog that could always catch its prey. The name comes from Greek *λαῖλαψ*, "hurricane".

But where does this word come from? [LSJ](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dlai%3Dlay) doesn't provide an etymology, and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BB%CE%B1%E1%BF%96%CE%BB%CE%B1%CF%88) doesn't even have a page for it.

Answer (score 2):

"Pre-Greek" according to Beekes.

Answer (score 1):

*Lailaps* is found in the New Testament. Textual studies of the Bible suggest its etymology to be "uncertain" (e.g. [here](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?t=nasb&strongs=g2978)).

Meanwhile, [this site](https://translate.academic.ru/%CE%BB%CE%B1%E1%BF%96%CE%BB%CE%B1%CF%88/el/xx/) has this:

[image]